# Two localhost site not sharing cookies though both authentication is against local identity server 4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have an issue with single sign-on with Identity server 4.

While I was following Identity server 4 (with aspnet core 2) videos and articles, I have developed a sample applications + identity server local. I have:

- Identity Server: https://locahost:5001
- Application 1: https://localhost:44373
- Application 2: https://localhost:44317

Both applications are the same Asp.net core 2 (MVC) except the client id. They have the same Authority https://localhost:5001

Now, When I tried to authenticate Application 1 against Identity server it's giving me the login page, authenticating the user (against aspnet identity) and giving me the home page back. I can see the claims are also coming as expected.

Same thing for Application 2 as well as Identity server.

But now the problem is:
If I complete the authentication for application 1 and try to refresh the page on Application 2 or Identity server nothing is authenticating. If I tries to access the secure page, it gives me the login screen from Identity server 4 as like there is no authentication has done. 
Same I tried to check by authenticating directly on Identity Server 4 and refreshing both the application (1 and 2) but no luck.

Seems like I am missing something. Here is my configuration:

Application side I have:

```
options.Authority = authenticationSettings.IdentityServer.Authority;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = bool.Parse(authenticationSettings.IdentityServer.RequireHttpsMetadata);
        options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        options.ClientId = authenticationSettings.IdentityServer.ClientId;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.ClientSecret = "secret";

        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("email");
```

In the Startup Class, the code for ConfigureServices is here...

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        AuthenticationSettings authenticationSettings = services.RegisterAuthenticationSettings(configuration: Configuration);

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
       .AddOpenIdConnect(options => SetOpenIdConnectOptions(options, authenticationSettings));

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }
```

For Configure Method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {

        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();
    }
```

Identity server side I have following client (same for application 1 and 2 except client id):

```
 new Client
            {
                ClientId = "mvc01",
                ClientName = "MVC 01 Demo",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
                ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                RequireConsent = false,
                RedirectUris =           { "https://localhost:44317/signin-oidc"},
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44317/signout-callback-oidc" },
                BackChannelLogoutUri = "https://localhost:44317/signout-callback-oidc",
                FrontChannelLogoutUri  = "https://localhost:44317/signout-callback-oidc",
                AllowedCorsOrigins =     { "https://localhost:44317" },
                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                    "office"
                }
            }
```

I also have tried to check the application info under chrome developer toolbar and found that they individually storing the cookies (.AspnetCore.Cookies, .AspnetCore.Cookies1, .AspnetCore.Cookies2) but that is for only that site) If I go to other application (where I haven't did sign-in) I am getting blank there.

Any suggestion?

After Anton, suggestion, this is the behavior:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include how you configure authentication oidc/cookie on clients, and your is4 side services too.

Comment: Hi Anton, I thought I have given those informations. I forgot to add HomeController Login Action Method and that is here..
public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = "/",
            }, 
            OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }

Comment: You didn't show all of it. Just include more of your services configuration on the client and server side.

Comment: I realized lately about that. Thanks for your note. I did it by editing original question itself. would you mind check the above question, you will get the ConfigureServices function there which might help you to understand my code and will help to suggest me better.

Comment: Hi Anton, any quick suggestion you can give?

Comment: Add `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` to your cookie service.`services.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)`, also ` AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true` should be `false` since you are using hybrid, and the Client backend, get's the token after the redirect from successful login from a back-channel, so it never happens in the browser, so just omit the property.

Comment: Have tried your suggestion. (1) CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme I though when I set DefaultAuthentication to CookiesAuthenticationDetails.AuthenticationScheme we don't have to set while we add .AddCookies explicitly. I have set that anyways. 
(2) I have change the GrantTypes.Implicit instead of Hybrid for now so, the AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true make ok sense for now. 
After all this change, I have tried but no luck. 
any more suggestion you can think of?

Comment: Have added your suggestion but not working. I have added two screenshots with initial question for your reference. (also have added comments in comment box for your two suggestions (above)

Comment: If you login on the Authentication Server alone (don't involve your clients) and refresh the page and the authentication cookies are lost, the problem is somewhere there (perhaps even your browser configuration). Otherwise If the authentication isn't lost, then use `AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials` for your clients. I would also recommend going through the documentation as you probably have been doing, and remove as much configuration as possible, keep only the necessary parts. https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html